# Tasker offline speech recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, offline

Anyone knows whether this is possible?
Allegedely this is possible from Android 4.2 onwards.
 (I have 4.4.2, Kazam Tornado 348, no mod)
I do find a "Offline Voice Recognition" setting in Settings > Language and Input > Google Voice Input, where I downloaded my language, which doesn't seem to help tough.
When saying "Ok google" while offline, the microphone screen shows, saying "Google is currently unavailable".

Comment: Hopefully it doesn't buffer your questions until a connection can be established – and then suddenly, and in the most inconvenient moment, starts answering aloud... #D // Couldn't find that either up to now. So if you find something, please don't forget to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)